# Concatenate a related column to another column of another table (with a common key)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for know-how with BigQuery,

I have two tables (t1 and t2) that are related to a common field (sku t1 and prod t2)

I need to concatenate a column (str t2) based on sku t1) and I haven't managed to do it.

I tried the following,

SELECT
t1.SKU,
CONCAT(t2.STR,',') AS LOAD
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.SKU = CAST(t2.PROD AS STRING)

This is table 1 (SKU)

| SKU | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| SKU1 | NAMEPRODUCT1 |
| SKU2 | NAMEPRODUCT2 |

This is table 2 (PROD)

| PROD | STR |
| --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 99 |
| SKU1 | 549 |
| SKU2 | 25 |
| SKU2 | 98 |

The output should be the following,

| SKU | LOAD |
| --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 99,549,1,97 |
| SKU2 | 25,98,2,88 |

Grateful for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!
What you're looking for is a `STRING_AGG`.
Try the following:

```
select
    t1.SKU
    , string_agg(cast(str as string),',')
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2
 on t1.SKU=cast(t2.prod as string)
group by t1.SKU
```

as a note, I am assuming the str column is an `INTEGER` which is why the cast is there, and I maintained your casting of the t2.prod column assuming it was not a string which is why you needed to cast it as one.

For more information on STRING_AGG see the docs here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you very much, you do not know how exciting and the lock you managed to unlock. Events like this inspire me to keep learning. I send you a hug from Chile!